# close tickets via groovy in JIRA

Tags: linux, apache, jira, load-balancing

Please explain what i must do to close tickets in JIRA. I try many variants but no one help me. 
There is my example :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Category
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.builder.JqlQueryBuilder
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Calendar
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.JiraServiceContextImpl
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import java.util.List

def Category log = Category.getInstance("com.onresolve.jira.groovy.PostFunction")
log.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG)

def user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
def ctx = new JiraServiceContextImpl(user)
def searchRequestService = ComponentManager.getInstance().getSearchRequestService()
def searchProvider = ComponentManager.getInstance().getSearchProvider()
def sr = searchRequestService.getFilter(ctx, 17540)
def searchResult = searchProvider.search(sr?.getQuery(), user, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
def issueManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueManager()
def issues = searchResult.getIssues().collect {issueManager.getIssueObject(it.id)}

for ( issue in issues ){
    def id=issue.getId()
}
return issues
```

It's works correctly. It get all issues from filter and show me or id or name like i wont.
What need insert in this script, what them close it? I mean change status to Resolved.

Thank, you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a transition between your issues state and the closed state and then execute this transition for each issue. You can figure out the id of your transition in the workflow menu (just display your workflow as text.

In this example you can see, how to execute a transition for a list of issues.

```
int actionId = 701; // transition id from Done to Closed    
for (Issue issue in issues) {
            log.info("Closing ${issue.key}: ${issue.summary}");
            IssueInputParameters params = cm.getIssueService().newIssueInputParameters();
            params.setRetainExistingValuesWhenParameterNotProvided(true);
            if (comment) params.setComment(comment);
            log.debug("Action parameters: ${params.actionParameters}");

            TransitionValidationResult validation = cm.getIssueService().validateTransition(user,issue.getId(),actionId,params);
            log.debug("Addition inputs: ${validation.additionInputs}");
            if (validation.isValid()) {
                IssueResult result = cm.getIssueService().transition(user,validation);
                if (result.isValid()) log.debug("${result.errorCollection}");
                else log.error("${result.errorCollection}");
            } else {
                result = null;
                log.error("Errors: ${validation.errorCollection.errors}");
            }
        }

        log.info("Done closing ${issues.size()} issue(s)");
```